# Como oculto algún elemento(Navbar, Footer) en Angular 8?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

buenas tardes a todos, estoy haciendo un Login, pero quiero ocultar el Navbar y el Footer, solamente cuando esté en el Login. Intenté haciendo esto

```
/* login.component.sass */
.navbar, .footer
    visibility: hidden !important
    display: none !important
```

y en el Typescript del Navbar

```
/* navbar.component.ts */    
styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.sass', '../../components/usuarios/login/login.component.sass']
```

Solamente que asi como lo tengo me lo aplica para todos mis Templates, obvio porque siempre está cargando los estilos de login.component.sass

Comment: Puedes utilizar un `*ngIf="ocultarComponente"`.

Comment: Tienes que explicar como pusiste tu layout para saber porque en esa página en particular no puedes cambiar el valor.